# How to create several empty lists at once?

Tags: r, list, assign, empty-list

I'd like to create 3 empty lists and assign them to different variables.

```
blue <- list()
green <- list()
red <- list()
```

Is there a possibility of a simultaneous assignment?

Comment: Do you really need them to be separate variables in your global environment? That's usually a red flag as far as best programming practives go. Normally it's much easier to work with similar data values inside a list itself. And if you are initializing with empty lists, that kind of implies you are going to be filling them up later and appending one item at a time to a list can be a slow operation in R. If a named list works, then `Map(function(...) list(), c("blue","green","red"))` would do the trick. You could use `list2env` is you really need to.

Comment: You are right, I'm using a for-loop to 'fill' the lists and the operation is way too slow...

`for(i in 1:length(files){
    blue[[i]] <- matrix.create(files[i])
    red[[i]] <- vector.create(files[i])
    green[[i]] <- vector.create(files[i])
}`

would it work using `map`?

Comment: And yes, the operation is very slow. `length(files)` is 20000.

Comment: How do I know if I need them as separate variables in the global environment? –

Comment: I don't know what these `vector.create` and `matrix.create` functions do. What packages are you using? It's better to initialize lists to their final size first and then fill them rather than assigning into non-existing indices. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
red <- blue <- green <- list()

ls()
[1] "blue"  "green" "red"
```

Note, that the lists at first have the same memory address,

```
sapply(list(red, blue, green), data.table::address)
# [1] "0x55ee16ce46a0" "0x55ee16ce46a0" "0x55ee16ce46a0"
```

but it will change as soon the objects are manipulated (i.e. a copy is created).

```
red[[1]] <- 'foo'; blue[[1]] <- 'foo'; green[[1]] <- 'foo'

sapply(list(red, blue, green), data.table::address)
# [1] "0x55ee16f1ea48" "0x55ee16f1e930" "0x55ee16f1e818"
```

Comment: Oh, thats nice!

Comment: will these reference the same list object or different objects? doing something like this in python will make all variables point to the same list.

Comment: I tried some simple loops and it seems that the variables point to different lists.

Comment: @qwr Yes, but this shouldn't matter, since addresses will change as soon you manipulate the objects. See edited answer.

Comment: If for some reason we're not happy with this issue, we can still use the `replicate` solution from [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76409194/1).

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure about R's copy on modify mechanic (I think it's covered in Advanced R by Hadley)